# Flutter App crashes when loading banners using google_mobile_ads

Tags: android, flutter, crash, google-mobile-ads

I am trying to load Rewarded Ads on a page but as soon as I navigate to the page the app crashes producing the following error.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8i2my.png)

I'm also getting the following error when the App is running

> E/GmsClient(15272): unable to connect to service: com.google.android.gms.leibniz.events.service.START on com.google.android.gms

Here is the flutter doctor output

[Flutter doctor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Qeou.png)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I added this dependency
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.2.0'    to app level build.gradle file  and error is gone also crash

Uh sorry i forgotted say another thing i used latest google mobile ads package

Comment: Please provide a detailed explanation to your answer, in order for the next user to understand your answer better.